# Is it possible to place a transparent view on top of another view and have clicks register to the bottom view?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

What I am basically trying to do is place a transparent view on top of my entire screen but have clicks still fire on the visibile view underneath.   The transparent view will have buttons on it, so I can't make the transparent view have a zIndex less then the bottom view or anything like that.

Wondering if this is at all possible??

Thank you!

Comment: what if you create the size as you need for the transparent view? Instead of full view size

Comment: @DouglasHennrich Unfortunatly I need it to cover the whole screen.  Basically I have a complex layout where on the top is a toolbar, and my transparent view contains buttons that get added to that toolbar.  Problem is  it covers up and disables clicks from reaching other icons on that toolbar that were already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a hack.

You could call the click event of the each underneath element from the click event of the transparent layer.

You would need to figure out where on the transparent layer the user clicked.

Also, it would make altering the layout underneath a lot of work also as you would need to retest and make sure the click points matched up.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying view components aren't directly accessible, as an inverse to `bubbleParent`.  However, it may be possible by mapping `x`, `y` touch coordinates of the veil to underlying positions (and `rect`) of child components and invoking `fireEvent` on the target view.  Not ideal, but could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to create a transparent view with buttons in it, or do you only need the buttons? If you use absolute positioning and zIndex for your button, and you would set the containing view to layout="composite", you wouldn't need a transparant view.

For example, the following code creates an image-view(full-width) with an icon overlay(or a button or whatever you want) on top of it:

```
<Alloy>
   <Window class="container">
       <View layout="composite">
           <View layout="vertical">
               <ImageView id="detailImage" image="/car.png" />
           </View>
           <ImageView id="backToMenu" image="menu.png" />
       </View>
```

The icon is absolute positioned and there is a click handler assigned to it:

```
"#backToMenu": {
  zIndex: 20,
  top: 10,
  left: 10,
  width: 24
}
```

It works smoothly, and I can still click on the picture below too (except there where the icon is rendered).